# Dropping rows from DataFrame with minutes in datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a DataFrame sy_wx as below:

[image]

And I wish to drop any row with minutes not equal to zero to look like.

[image]

Using

```
sy_wx = sy_wx[sy_wx['time_utc'].minute == 0]
```

gives AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'minute' error

but

```
In [50]: sy_wx['time_utc'][1].minute
Out[50]: 30
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

first, make sure your datatype for `time_utc` column is DateTime. You can convert object(str) to DateTime using this code:

```
sy_wx['time_utc'] = pd.to_datetime(sy_wx['time_utc'])
```

then use this code to filter your data:

```
sy_wx = sy_wx[sy_wx['time_utc'].dt.minute == 0]
```

you are missing `dt` before `minute`

Answer (score 1):

We need use `dt` to get the minute

```
sy_wx = sy_wx[sy_wx['time_utc'].dt.minute == 0].copy() # also add copy at the end , for set copy error
```

Comment: Thanks @YOBEN_S. Any chance you could elaborate on the .copy() at the end?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas @Tim